# Find Median in a colored range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, median

**I have the following issue to solve in Excel 2010 VBA code**

In `Range("A:A")` I have lots of numeric values. Only some of them are highlighted in color.  (`index = 6` [yellow]). I need Excel VBA code to obtain the Median between the yellow highlighted values and leave the non highlighted cells outside the computation.

I have made code tries but it always gives me the first value in the highlighted range and not the Median value of the range.

```
Dim amarelosMediana As Range
Dim mediana As Double

For Each amarelosMediana In Range([a1], Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If amarelosMediana.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        mediana = Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(amarelosMediana)
    End If
Next amarelosMediana

ActiveSheet.Range("C3") = "Mediana no intervalo de confianca"
ActiveSheet.Range("D3") = mediana
```

As you can see I used `Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(amarelosMediana)` as stated in some tutorials here in stackoverflow to obtain the Median value, but it doesn't work.

**Any ideas ??**

Comment: That's because you give the "Median" only one argument (one cell) at a time.

Comment: Humm! So you are saying that i have to give all the cells. But the amarelosMediana Range has hall the cells in it, isn't it ? Or the amarelosMediana Range as only the first cell of the range stored ?

Comment: "For Each" means one at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  Fixed some syntax.  You have to pass all the highlighted cells into one master range then run the function on the master range.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim amarelosMediana As Range
Dim tempRng As Range
Dim mediana As Double

Set tempRng = Nothing
For Each amarelosMediana In Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If amarelosMediana.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        If tempRng Is Nothing Then
            Set tempRng = amarelosMediana
        Else
            Set tempRng = Union(tempRng, amarelosMediana)
        End If
    End If
Next amarelosMediana

mediana = Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(tempRng)
ActiveSheet.Range("C3") = "Mediana no intervalo de confianca"
ActiveSheet.Range("D3") = mediana
End Sub
```

Comment: SOLVED. Many thanks Chrismas007 for the time spent and the excellent fix provided. Now the Median appears with correct value.